# How to create a multi dimension data using d3js?

Tags: d3.js

I have a combination of dimensions to display using d3.js

What chart or graph do I use to represent data like this?

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "x": 2.4,
            "y": 3.2,
            "z": 84,
            "t": 1060
        },
        {
            "x": 2.1,
            "y": -3.0,
            "z": 99,
            "t": 1140
        },
        {
            "x": 3.1,
            "y": -4.4,
            "z": 88,
            "t": 1090
        },
        {
            "x": 3.7,
            "y": -3.4,
            "z": 98,
            "t": 1190
        },
    ]
}
```

I have tried looking at d3 documentation but couldn't see an example for multi dimensional data

Comment: Can you provide an illustration of the desired graph?

Comment: Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70723644/765395 ?